# variable i=i +1 for visible cells

Tags: excel, filtering, rows

I would like to ask. I have a code that works perfectly. The problem comes when the user filters the data in Excel. Some rows will be hidden. Then the variable i = i + 1 does not work. (Works but runs through all lines)
Basically, I'm asking how can I set a variable for visible rows only?
Thank you for help!

````
i = 2
Do
 'If Sheets("FORMAT").Cells(i, 7) Like "*IE-12-2007984*" Then
  'End If
  On Error GoTo Handler
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_VBUKR").Text = "1200"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").Text = "AKTUALIZACE"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(0, "TXT04")
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
Handler2:
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7)

i = i + 1
If Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then Exit Do
Loop
If Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then

Set session = Nothing
Connection.CloseSession ("ses[0]")
Set Connection = Nothing
Set SAP = Nothing
MsgBox "HOTOVO"
Exit Sub
Handler:
 Resume Handler2
 End If
End Sub```
````

Comment: `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

Comment: Please don't indicate SAP GUI and SAP GUI Scripting code, as your question is only about Excel row filtering. You should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your write just after "do"

```
   If Not ActiveSheet.rows(i).Hidden then
     goto endOfLoop
   EndIf
```

and then at the end just before "loop" we put our target, we change the condition of the loop to `j`and put the incrementation of `j` to after the target to avoid having an infinite loop.

```
EndOfLoop:
j = j + 1
loop
```

none of the code in between will run for hidden rows. We do not increment i for hidden rows so i counts the visible rows.You will need to declare and initialise `Dim j as integer = 2` before the loop, just after `i = 2` .
NB The use of `Option Explicit` and properly declared variables is strongly recommended.
`COMPLETE CODE REVISED`

```
i = 2
Dim j As Integer                                                                    'LINE ADDED
j = 2                                                                   'LINE ADDED
Do
   If Not ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Hidden Then                                'LINE ADDED
     GoTo EndOfLoop                                                      'LINE ADDED
   End If                                                                'LINE ADDED
 'If Sheets("FORMAT").Cells(i, 7) Like "*IE-12-2007984*" Then
  'End If
  On Error GoTo Handler
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_VBUKR").Text = "1200"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").Text = "AKTUALIZACE"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(0, "TXT04")
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
Handler2:
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7)

i = i + 1
If Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then Exit Do
EndOfLoop:                                                                'LINE ADDED
j = j + 1                                                                 'LINE ADDED
Loop
If Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then

Set session = Nothing
Connection.CloseSession ("ses[0]")
Set Connection = Nothing
Set SAP = Nothing
MsgBox "HOTOVO"
Exit Sub
Handler:
 Resume Handler2
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's look as good solutions but, what about  this variable? Which saying where should start.  I have thsi variable before Do : I=2

Comment: I edited the ecode just for this variable I=2 tahts before Do, I understand that variable can start in row 2, but I want start with this variable in first visible row after filtering. Sorry for editing, I could do that in the beginning

Comment: We can add a second variable and use one for the loop and one for counting the active lines.see modification

Comment: I'm completely lost in it sorry. I ll edit my questions what i did in code

Comment: I misunderstood you, can you please give me more detailed instructions?

Comment: I've put the complete code with the additions at the end of my answer.

Comment: It finally works. I only had to edit a few lines, but I still have one problem, the macro doesn't end and the OLE message pops up.  I ll edit the code which is working for me.  On line 18(5TH LINE FROM THE END) I have the command "Then Exit Do", why can't the macro recognize him?Thank you for helping me. 
I could never have done it without you.

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote the answer if you can.

Comment: Problem is with filter, as picture shows. I'm working with visible rows after filtering and then the command for "exit do" can't find this row(Actually command can find this row, but his value is no "". So is it here some other way how to end this macro? If he copy all values?

Answer (score 0):

["the first empty row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KF7x.png)[SOME ROWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvKWk.png) Here is just couple of rows. I asked  fot the wrong question maybe. So I would like to get value from first visible row and continue to next one visible rows and again. I tried what u wrote here. And still doesn't work.
Here is What I did, (I didn't revise loop, just for now)
I'm getting now value from first hidden row and continue +1 row.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Do
If Sheet("Stavby").Rows(i).Hidden Then
     GoTo EndOfLoop
   End If
  On Error GoTo Handler
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_VBUKR").Text = "1200"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_VARI").Text = "AKTUALIZACE"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 2).Value = myGrid.getcellvalue(0, "TXT04")
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
Handler2:
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_PSPID-LOW").Text = Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7)
If Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then Exit Do
EndOfLoop:
i = i + 1
Loop
If Sheets("Stavby").Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then
```

Comment: you havn't said what the aim of your code is. Maybe you could write a new question saying this is what I am trying to do, this is my code, which works unless their are filtered rows which match the condition but I dont want them if they are filtered.

Comment: I ll open the new question